# Notify client when closing server via socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm creating a socket program. The server is always listening to client request and send a response. When user click button in GUI, the client will send a request to server.

My problem is I want to notify the client that server has been closed when I click close button in GUI in server. I have come up with an idea that create a new connection to client always listen to server, but I think it is wasting resources.

`server.py`

```py
while True:
    try:
        request = client.recv(BUFSIZE).decode('utf-8')
    except ConnectionResetError:
        logging.info(str(client.getsockname()) + ' has exited')
        break
    except Exception as e:
        continue
    if request:
        try:
            request = json.loads(request)
            response = self.__handle_request(request, client).encode()
            client.send(response)
```

`client.py`

```py
# when user client button
sock.send(request)
response = sock.recv().decode()
render(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

The client socket IS notified when the server socket closes.  Your client's `sock.recv` call will return a zero-length packet, the only instance in which it does so.

Comment: My client program only calls function recv when user click a button on the GUI. I want to notify client immediately without clicking any button.

Comment: If no one is listening on the socket, how on earth do you think the client is going to hear your "I'm dying!" message?  You need to spin off a thread to listen continuously.  It's easy and costs nothing.  A thread that is blocked waiting for socket data uses 0 resources.